# How to set webview scroll position within it on initial launch?

Tags: android

I have an issue with Webview to set the initial scroll position within it when first launched. By default it is left , I want it to scroll and show the view from center. 
Or is it possible to resize the view to fit the screen width initially, instead of scroll bars.
I need this since the left part of the page I am loading is blank making user feel the page is not loaded.

Comment: because there have not been any satisfactory answer for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There did not seem to be a solution. I managed to loop back the large page to as smaller as possible by calling zoom out in loop before displaying it.